# Name that pattern: Notifications on reaching bottom of page

Tags: website-design, design-patterns

Over the last couple of months I have begun to see a pattern, but I don't know what it's called.

The concept is that when a user scrolls to the end of the page, or a point close to the end of the main content, an animated dialog appears, usually outside the main flow in a side area. This then usually persists unless dismissed, or unless the user scrolls back up to the top.

I'm tempted to call this thing a 'just-in-time notification', because it appears just after I've finished consuming the content it relates to - **but is there a better name?**

### Example:

You can see an implementation of this pattern here: http://mashable.com/2012/05/30/kings-social-media/

*At the top of the page, there's nothing in the sidebar...*

[image: state1]

*But then we scroll down, and as we reach the end of the article...*

[image: state2]

*A social media / share widget pops up in the bottom right.*

Comment: I don't know an official name for the pattern, but unofficially I call it $%#^& annoying. Almost every time I notice one of these things it's not native to the site itself but some kind of plug-in add-on trying to drive traffic elsewhere. I suspect they're from some kind of third party network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SimpleReach Slide. A post-read discovery tool. That is, a tool that helps you discover new content after you are done with reading the current page.

Comment: Googling suggests that that's the name of the specific plugin, but I wonder if the term 'slide' is a bit nonspecific.